# Setting up Celery with Postgres as broker - No such transport 'db'

Tags: postgresql, celery

I am currently trying to set up postgres as a broker to Celery:

```
broker = "db+postgresql://guest:guest@postgres-localnet/test_db"
app = Celery('tasks', broker=broker)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

When I try to add a message/task:

```
>>> import app.tasks as t
>>> t.add.delay(1,2)
```

I get the following error message:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/__init__.py", line 64, in resolve_transport
    raise KeyError('No such transport: {0}'.format(transport))
KeyError: 'No such transport: db'
```

According to the docs (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#database-url-examples), it looks like this should work.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: I finally figured it out. It looks like kombu doesnt like db. Instead, you have to use alchemy (i.e. sqla)

Comment: The docs that you referenced are for the results backend, not for the broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of celery 4.2, you can't use a database as a broker.  According to the documentation, [only four brokers are supported](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.2.0/getting-started/brokers/index.html#broker-overview):

- redis
- rabbitmq
- sqs
- zookeeper

For kombu-level transports, you can consult [this reference](http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/latest/userguide/connections.html#transport-comparison).